# Trying to implement CountryPicker from github. No errors in code, app crashes, a lot of logcat errors

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-fragments, android-fragmentactivity

It seems that I am asking something that has been asked in the past, but nobody else managed to get an answer for, therefore fingers crossed.

I am trying to implement   [the CountryPicker from github](https://github.com/roomorama/AndroidCountryPicker). However it doesn't seem to work. I had tried 2 out 3 possible ways to implement it (at least I think there were 3).

1. First one was to add the CountryPicker code inside my application and
   on top of that implement the sample folder code (didnt work)
2. Second one was to somehow change the fragmentactivity code to
   activity (havent tried that yet)
3. Third one was to import the CountryPicker code as a library. I think
   that was the right way to do it, therefore I have listed the steps I
   have done to make it work.

---

1. First I have created new android project called CountryPickerApp and implemented the code from the sample folder found within that countrypicker repository. Here's the code for MainActivity.class:

   ```
    package com.example.countrypickerapp;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
    import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
    import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
    import android.view.Menu;
    import android.view.MenuItem;
    import android.view.MenuItem.OnMenuItemClickListener;
    import android.widget.Toast;

    import com.countrypicker.CountryPicker;
    import com.countrypicker.CountryPickerListener;

    public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

     @Override
     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

       FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
       FragmentTransaction transaction = manager.beginTransaction();

       CountryPicker picker = new CountryPicker();
       picker.setListener(new CountryPickerListener() {

           @Override
           public void onSelectCountry(String name, String code) {
               Toast.makeText(
                       MainActivity.this,
                       "Country Name: " + name + " - Code: " + code
                               + " - Currency: "
                               + CountryPicker.getCurrencyCode(code),
                       Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
           }
       });

       transaction.replace(R.id.home, picker);

       transaction.commit();

   }

   @Override
   public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
       // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
       getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
       MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.show_dialog);
       item.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new OnMenuItemClickListener() {

           @Override
           public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
               CountryPicker picker = CountryPicker.newInstance("Select Country");
               picker.setListener(new CountryPickerListener() {

                   @Override
                   public void onSelectCountry(String name, String code) {
                       Toast.makeText(
                               MainActivity.this,
                               "Country Name: " + name + " - Code: " + code
                                       + " - Currency: "
                                       + CountryPicker.getCurrencyCode(code),
                               Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                   }
               });

               picker.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "COUNTRY_PICKER");
               return false;
           }
       });
       return true;
   }
   ```

   }
2. Here's the code for the AndroidManifest.xml file

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   package="com.example.countrypickerapp"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

   <uses-sdk
       android:minSdkVersion="8"
       android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

   <application
       android:allowBackup="true"
       android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
       android:label="@string/app_name"
       android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
       <activity
          android:name="com.example.countrypickerapp.Main1Activity"
           android:label="@string/app_name" android:parentActivityName="@string/title_activity_main1">
           <intent-filter>
               <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

               <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
           </intent-filter>
       </activity>
       <activity
          android:name="com.example.countrypickerapp.MainActivity"
          android:label="@string/title_activity_main1" >
       </activity>
   </application>

   </manifest>
   ```
3. As far as I understood the main folder (CountryPicker) had to be imported as a library so i followed those steps:

> ```
> File->New->Other
> Select Android Project
> Select "Create Project from existing source"
> Click "Browse..." button and navigate to johannilsson-android-actionbar\actionbar
> Finish (Now action bar project in your workspace)
> Right-click on your project -> Properties
> In Android->Library section click Add
> select recently added project -> Ok
> ```

1. And here is the list of logcat log errors:

   ```
   11-17 02:06:37.320: I/SurfaceTextureClient(9657): [STC::queueBuffer] this:0x4fa637f8, api:1, last queue time elapsed :5603 ms
   11-17 02:06:37.321: I/SurfaceTextureClient(9657): [0x4fa637f8] frames:2, duration:5.603000, fps:0.356932
   11-17 02:06:37.325: W/MMUMapper(9657): fail to register MVA, unsupported format(0x5)
   11-17 02:06:37.413: W/ActionMenuPresenter(9657): showOverflowMenu fail, mReserveOverflow=true, mMenu.getNonActionItems().size()=1, isOverflowMenuShowing()=false
   11-17 02:06:37.476: W/MMUMapper(9657): fail to register MVA, unsupported format(0x5)
   11-17 02:06:37.490: W/MMUMapper(9657): fail to register MVA, unsupported format(0x5)
   11-17 02:06:37.510: W/MMUMapper(9657): fail to register MVA, unsupported format(0x5)
   11-17 02:06:38.094: W/MMUMapper(9657): invalid operation for unregister MVA with VA(0x52b85000) size(57344) f(0x5)
   11-17 02:06:38.094: W/MMUMapper(9657): invalid operation for unregister MVA with VA(0x52cec000) size(57344) f(0x5)
   11-17 02:06:38.095: W/MMUMapper(9657): invalid operation for unregister MVA with VA(0x52cfa000) size(57344) f(0x5)
   11-17 02:06:38.102: W/InputEventReceiver(9657): Attempted to finish an input event but the input event receiver has already been disposed.
   11-17 02:06:40.889: W/MMUMapper(9657): invalid operation for unregister MVA with VA(0x528cf000) size(614400) f(0x5)
   11-17 02:06:40.890: W/MMUMapper(9657): invalid operation for unregister MVA with VA(0x52d6d000) size(614400) f(0x5)
   11-17 02:06:40.890: W/MMUMapper(9657): invalid operation for unregister MVA with VA(0x52aa9000) size(614400) f(0x5)
   11-17 02:10:40.214: E/Trace(10401): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
   11-17 02:10:40.316: W/dalvikvm(10401): Unable to resolve superclass of Lcom/example/countrypickerapp/MainActivity; (11)
   11-17 02:10:40.316: W/dalvikvm(10401): Link of class 'Lcom/example/countrypickerapp/MainActivity;' failed
   11-17 02:10:40.317: E/dalvikvm(10401): Could not find class 'com.example.countrypickerapp.MainActivity', referenced from method com.example.countrypickerapp.Main1Activity$1.onClick
   11-17 02:10:40.317: W/dalvikvm(10401): VFY: unable to resolve const-class 57 (Lcom/example/countrypickerapp/MainActivity;) in Lcom/example/countrypickerapp/Main1Activity$1;
   11-17 02:10:40.505: W/MMUMapper(10401): fail to register MVA, unsupported format(0x5)
   11-17 02:10:40.615: W/MMUMapper(10401): fail to register MVA, unsupported format(0x5)
   11-17 02:10:42.480: I/SurfaceTextureClient(10401): [0x4fa637f8] frames:2, duration:1.945000, fps:1.027828
   11-17 02:10:42.499: W/MMUMapper(10401): fail to register MVA, unsupported format(0x5)
   11-17 02:10:42.619: W/dalvikvm(10401): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41269908)
   11-17 02:10:42.638: E/AndroidRuntime(10401): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
   11-17 02:10:42.638: E/AndroidRuntime(10401): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.example.countrypickerapp.MainActivity
   11-17 02:10:42.638: E/AndroidRuntime(10401): at com.example.countrypickerapp.Main1Activity$1.onClick(Main1Activity.java:22)
   11-17 02:10:42.638: E/AndroidRuntime(10401): at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4091)
   11-17 02:10:42.638: E/AndroidRuntime(10401): at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17072)
   11-17 02:10:42.638: E/AndroidRuntime(10401): at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
   11-17 02:10:42.638: E/AndroidRuntime(10401): at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
   11-17 02:10:42.638: E/AndroidRuntime(10401): at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:153)
   11-17 02:10:42.638: E/AndroidRuntime(10401): at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5037)
   11-17 02:10:42.638: E/AndroidRuntime(10401): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
   11-17 02:10:42.638: E/AndroidRuntime(10401): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
   11-17 02:10:42.638: E/AndroidRuntime(10401): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:825)
   11-17 02:10:42.638: E/AndroidRuntime(10401): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:588)
   11-17 02:10:42.638: E/AndroidRuntime(10401): at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
   ```

Additonally I have added an additional Activity called MainActivity1 which has a button, which when clicked redirects to MainActivity where CountryPicker is implemented.

I hope I have explained my problem well and will get either a solution, tip, hint or anything which could get me closer to getting it to work. I know that I could have reimplemented all of it from scratch using different methods, but I don't see a point of reinventing something that has been already been implemented and uploaded for sharing, apart from learning something new of course.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your manifest declares **Main 1 Activity** (space added to highlight the numeric 1) but your class file is MainActivity.java without the 1 !! :)

Comment: It's because after implementing the code for MainActivity, it is no longer seen as Activity. The only visible Activity is the MainActivity1, which I've added later, because I thought it might resolve the problem. I am working on making sure the manifest file is correct, but the app wasn't working before I made additional activity(MainActivity1). I am unsure why MainActivity, which extends FragmentActivity is no longer seen as Activity. I'm sorry if I misunderstood you.

Comment: Are you sure You have exported the Android Support Library?

Comment: There was actually a problem with the Support library, so I had to define my own path to it (linked the one in CountryPicker libs folder). The one within my application(libs folder) on its own wasn't detected? I get a warning about jar file mismatch. I will add that into the my orginal post.

Comment: It seem's that you are exporting it in both the places. Go to Project Properties --> Java Build Path --> Order and Export. Uncheck the support library. Also, make sure you have the same jar in both your project and Android library that you are using.

Comment: So should I copy the support jar file from the CountryPicker library to my application or vice versa? In Order and Export the library I have referenced is unchecked.

Comment: Copy from the library to your project and make sure you export it at only one the places.

Comment: OMG I fixed it! All i had to do is CHECK the box for that library in Order and Export, which was originally unchecked! Thanks a lot dude! Good thing I decided to try it haha